# Numerically approximating a linear ODE by extending the analytical solution of the simpler form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to solve the following linear ODE:

$$\tau\frac{dV(t)}{dt}=-V(t)+I(t)\tag{1}\label{1}$$

If $I(t)=I$ is independent of time, the solution is written as follows:

$$V(t)=I+(V(t_0)-I)\exp(\frac{-(t-t_0)}{\tau})\tag{2}\label{2}$$

I am interested in the numeric approximation of $V(t)$ when $I(t)$ is time dependent. I have seen derivations, where the solution above is extended for $I(t)$ being time dependent. The assumption here is that over a small time interval $\Delta t$ we assume $I(t)=I$ to be constant.

$$V(t+\Delta t)=I+(V(t)-I)\exp(\frac{-\Delta t}{\tau})\tag{3}\label{3}$$

Such a solution intuitively seems to make sense, however I have not previously seen such solutions. I would rather have solved such an ODE $\eqref{1}$ using finite difference methods such as the Euler or Runge-Kutta method. For example, solving the ODE using Euler method gives

$$V(t+\Delta t)=\frac{\Delta t}{\tau} \big( I(t) - V(t) \big) + V(t) \tag{4}\label{4}$$

However, I see that Taylor approximating the exponential in $\eqref{3}$ shows that $\eqref{3}$ is approximately equivalent to $\eqref{4}$. My questions are as follows

1. How is this method know as, where you analytically solve ODEs and then extend the closed form solution to a numeric approximation (as done from $\eqref{2}$ to $\eqref{3}$)?
2. Is the analytically extended solution $\eqref{3}$ a better approximation than the Euler solution $\eqref{4}$? How does the error scale?

Thanks!

Comment: See exponential Euler method. There are also higher order exponential methods, and then also Rosenbrock methods that follow a similar strategy. Essentially you apply the numerical method to $U(t)=e^{(t-t_0)/\tau}V(t)$ for which the ODE simplifies.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, this is what I was looking for. Can you recommend any good resources to learn more about the exponential Euler method?

Comment: I have nothing but the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integrator and the references there. The books "Solving ODE" by Hairer et al. also contain sections on this topic.

Comment: Dankschön, I will have a look at the book

Answer (score 1):

Define a $V_1=V(t)-V_c(t)$, where $V_c(t)$ is the solution to the constant $I$ equation.  Then you get
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV_1}{dt}+\frac{dV_c}{dt}$$
and solving for $V'$ and using the fact that $V_c$ is a solution to the "Constant equation" (with presumably the constant $I=I(0)$yields
$$\frac{dV_1}{dt}=-V_1(t)+I(t)-I_0$$
which can be solved with the numerical scheme you prefer.